# \setbool not respected in footnote?

Tags: footnotes, conditionals, etoolbox

Can someone explain why `\setbool` (from `etoolbox`) is not respected when used in a command *only* used in a footnote?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\longshort}[1][]{%
  \providebool{ls}%
  \ifbool{ls}%
  % bool = true = not first time
  {This is the #1 time\ldots}%
  % bool = false = first time
  {This is the first time the command is used!}%
  \setbool{ls}{true}%
}

\begin{document}

1:% \longshort%
\footnote{\longshort[2nd]}

2:% \longshort[3rd]
\footnote{%
% \providebool{ls}%   uncomment these two lines to get
% \setbool{ls}{true}% expected behaviour
\longshort[4th]}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the intent to follow a different conditional branch at the first call compared to subsequent calls?

Comment: @Werner -- Yes.  I thought it'd be an easy way to 'track' whether a custom citation command had been used or not; if not, then give a 'full' citation; if yes, then give an abbreviated version.  (This is why it's only used in footnotes.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct definition of `\longshort` should be:

```
\providebool{ls}%
\newcommand{\longshort}[1][]{%
  \ifbool{ls}%
  % bool = true = not first time
  {This is the #1 time\ldots}%
  % bool = false = first time
  {This is the first time the command is used!}%
  \global\booltrue{ls}%
}
```

where `ls` is set to `true` with a `\global` prefix. Otherwise the assignment doesn't survive the group it is called within. Also, `ls` is defined *outside* `\longshort`.

Comment: Hmm, yes.  And `\providebool` has to be outside the command definition.  I'd rather if everything could be inside the `\newcommand`, but it's not that big a deal I guess.

Comment: @jon You'd make LaTeX spin its wheels for nothing at every call of `\longshort` trying to see whether the `ls` boolean is already defined. The macro `\longshort` *uses* the boolean, which therefore should be defined before it. And `\newbool` is better: you'll be warned if some package defines it; otherwise you won't get any warning/error and you may end up disrupting the package's and your own work.

Comment: @egreg -- That makes sense.  I actually had a working solution before (not quite as compressed/elegant), but I got obsessed with making everything self-contained.  The thing that was bugging me was simply that there seemed to be no way for a boolean defined (`provide`-d) in a footnote to be seen globally.  But I wasn't thinking at all about making LaTeX do extra work all the time for such a small gain....